# Error "the application server could not be contacted" pgadmin4 Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin

He actualizado mi SO a Ubuntu 19.04, venía usando pgadmin4 en ubuntu 18.10 y funcionaba sin problemas, ahora que actualizo me sale este error:

"the application server could not be contacted"

Probé desinstalando el pgadmin4 y reinstalando pero sin mejoras...

También reactive el repositorio de postgresql porque al actualizar a ubuntu 19.04 desactivo algunos repositorios

Answer (score 0):

Intenta instalando pgadmin4 con apache:

```
sudo apt install pgadmin4 pgadmin4-apache2
```

Y accedes por la siguiente URL: http://localhost/pgadmin4/

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Reinicia los servicios de PostgreSQL:

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

Para ver el estado del servidor:

```
sudo systemctl status postgresql
```